# What's the difference between node-debug and node-inspector?

Tags: node.js, debugging, remote-debugging

Looks like node-debug is a shell around node-inspector? When should each be used?

Comment: According to "[*Advanced Use*](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector#advanced-use)," `node-debug` is the simpler command. If it's sufficient, use it. If you need more control (e.g. "[*How do I specify files to hide?*](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector#how-do-i-specify-files-to-hide)"), use `node-inspector`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install **node-debug**, you only get access to the node-debug command.
If you install **node-inspector**, you will have both the node-debug command and the node-inspector command that includes more options, see https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-inspector

All node-debug is

> Quick and easy wrapper for node-inspector

From https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-debug